# How do I break a link in java (using @link or @see tags) if I cannot use more than 80 characters?

Tags: tags, hyperlink, javadoc

I have the following problem when using javadoc the @see tags: I cannot exceed the 80 characters but the link itself is longer than that. How can I break it to comply with that restriction?
For example, if I want to use a @see tag to refer the javadoc reader to the Java Naming Conventions, how can I break it in two lines without affecting the javadoc?
The link is:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following Javadoc worked without any problem for me:

```
/**
 * Some content.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367">Java Naming Conventions</a>
 */
```

It then generated an appropriate `See Also:` section with the link correctly displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [URL shortener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening). For example, you could use [**`https://goo.gl/`**](https://goo.gl/) (from Google) to generate a a short URL to put it in the *JavaDoc*.